# Use of “in a state” or “as”

Tags: meaning

> They decided to produce the door in two cm longer state.

> They decided to produce the door as two cm longer.

Are either of these two sentences grammatically correct? I am trying to describe the door they will produce.

Comment: [correction: how they will be produced]. state is wrong here. It's two centimeters longer.

Comment: "in **a** two-centimeter longer state" is grammatically correct, but very "wordy" and clumsy.  It sounds very strange.  Don't use it.

Comment: Doors are usually made or manufactured. You might be trying to say, "They decided to make a door that was two cms longer."

Comment: You could say _...in a size 2cm higher than the previous one._ The longer dimension of a door becomes its height when in place.

Comment: It's not merely "clumsy", it can lead to unintended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> They decided to produce the door in two cm longer state.

> They decided to produce the door as two cm longer.

Neither of these are correct.

Instead, say:

**They decided to produce a version of the door that was two centimeters longer.**

or

**They decided to produce the door two centimeters longer.**

Answer (score -2):

If they are making the door starting from raw materials you could say

> They decided to make the door that was two cms longer
> They decided to make the door that was two cms longer than the previous one
> They decided to make the door that was two cms longer

following OldBrixtonian's comment. In all three cases *a door* might be better than *the door* unless in is a specific door which has been discussed already in the conversation

If the door exists and they are altering it you could say

> They decided to make the door two cms longer
> They decided to increase the length of the door by 2 cms

in this case *the door* is fine since it is clearly one specific door which is the issue.

Comment: The use of the indefinite article in the first set of examples does not sound correct for OP's intended meaning, and you repeat the exact same usage once.